# MikTex with psgo package: cannot render more than 7 moves?

Tags: miktex

I am using the packgage psgo to render board game of Go in an IEEE paper.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{psgo}

\UseRawInputEncoding

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!thbp]
 \setcounter{gomove}{0}
 \setgounit{0.3cm}
 %\scriptsize{
 \tiny{
 \begin{center}
 \begin{psgoboard}[19]
 \move{b}{2}
 \move{c}{3}
 \move{d}{4}
 \move{e}{5}
 \move{f}{6}
 \move{g}{7}
 \move{h}{8}
 \move{i}{9}
 \end{psgoboard}
 \caption{Lee Sedol vs AlphaGoZero - Game2 (“Invention”)}
 \label{Figure:LS-vs-AG-Game2}
 \end{center}
 }
\end{figure}
  
word word 
  
\end{document}
```

it renders well but when I want to add more stones using an additional
\move{i}{9} MikTex stops and I get a "Missing number, treated as zero."
So I am wondering how to add more stones (with counter number).
I am trying to render a whole game.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.43  \move{i}{9}
```

Thank you very much in advance for any pointers.

Brahim :: Singapore

Comment: Show a complete example. That makes is much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Done. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation says

> the columns are indexed by A,B, . . . , T (skipping I)

So use j instead of i for the next move:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{psgo}

\UseRawInputEncoding

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!thbp]
 \setcounter{gomove}{0}
 \setgounit{0.3cm}
 %\scriptsize{
 \tiny{
 \begin{center}
 \begin{psgoboard}[19]
 \move{b}{2}
 \move{c}{3}
 \move{d}{4}
 \move{e}{5}
 \move{f}{6}
 \move{g}{7}
 \move{h}{8}
 \move{j}{9}
 \end{psgoboard}
 \caption{Lee Sedol vs AlphaGoZero - Game2 (“Invention”)}
 \label{Figure:LS-vs-AG-Game2}
 \end{center}
 }
\end{figure}

word word

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Only engineers would substitute *j* for *i*. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you Ulrike ! I overlooked this one !