# PSGO Package Yielding OS Permission Denied Error on Mac TeX Live

Tags: pstricks

The [`psgo`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/psgo/) package is actually within the basic install of TeXLive, which makes this all the weirder to me.

This is the code I'm trying to use, which happens to be a replica of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549516/64441):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{psgo}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!thbp]
    \setcounter{gomove}{0}
    \setgounit{0.3cm}
    %\scriptsize{
    \tiny{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{psgoboard}[19]
    \move{b}{2}
    \move{c}{3}
    \move{d}{4}
    \move{e}{5}
    \move{f}{6}
    \move{g}{7}
    \move{h}{8}
    \move{j}{9}
    \end{psgoboard}
    \caption{Lee Sedol vs AlphaGoZero - Game2 (“Invention”)}
    \label{Figure:LS-vs-AG-Game2}
    \end{center}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code should have generated this:

[image: correct output]

But all I get is this, besides the lovely, super readable errors:

[image: actual result]

In VS Code, this is the error transcript:

```
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--
Operand stack:
   (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   run   run   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   run
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:756/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
Current file position is 69
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--
Operand stack:
   (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   run   run   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   run
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:756/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
Current file position is 69
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
 )
```

In TeXMaker, I just get a bunch of `Undefined control sequence` errors.

What is going on here? This is apparently a permissions error which seems to have a solution on [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288670/64441), however, using `chmod -R 755` on my TeX Live folder did *not* solve the problem so far.

> LaTeX does work fine without the use of the `psgo` package, I do have a functional installation.

Comment: You should probably provide the full compilation log, and which latex engine are you using here?

Comment: For me `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` works, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex` fails with different errors

Comment: @daleif, you mean something like [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/baduk/comments/2kkaki/psgo_go_diagrams_for_latex/)? (I've just found it)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the optional argument `-dNOSAFER` for `ps2pdf` otherwise Ghostscript doesn't run external files (the PSTricks pro files).

for newer Ghostscript >= 9.5x use

```
 ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY <file>.ps
```

or

```
 ps2pdf -dNOSAFER <file>.ps
```

And if you used `xelatex` then update your TeX distribution. There was a bug in `xdvipdfmx.cfg`

Comment: But how would the complete process look like? From [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/baduk/comments/2kkaki/psgo_go_diagrams_for_latex/), I gather it would be something like `latex <file>.tex && dvips -P pdf <file>.dvi && ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENC <file>.ps`? (This hasn't worked so far) And how would I automate it in VS Code? Or will I always need to use the terminal then?

Comment: Running the command on my previous comment generated a `.ps` file which didn't feature the game diagram (I opened the file in Adobe Illustrator to check it).

Comment: After a few more attempts, it's giving me `Error: /undefined in .setopacityalpha`.

Comment: Do you have macTeX 2021?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've installed in the last few days. And, even if I don't, I can uninstall everything and get the most up-to-date version, that's not a problem.

Comment: No problem with TeXlive2022 and LuaLaTeX

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what my setup was way back then, but I've just tried it with what's mentioned in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/baduk/comments/2kkaki/psgo_go_diagrams_for_latex/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and it worked:

```bash
latex go.tex
dvips -P pdf go.dvi
ps2pdf go.ps
```

I don't know what the difference to @user187802's answer is exactly.